# Envió de archivo Excel por bloques

Tags: java, spring-boot

tengo un problema con el envio de un excel por bloques, tengo este código que supuestamente envia el excel por bloques, hasta cierto punto lo hace bien pero el problema es que solo escribe los primeros 100 registros, posteriormente el archivo sigue pesando como si fueran los 10000 registros pero al abrirlo solo tiene 100

```
@Override
public void generateAndSendExcelChunks(ServletOutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    // Crear un libro de Excel con SXSSFWorkbook para trabajar con archivos grandes
    Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();

    // Crear una hoja de Excel en el libro
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datos");

    // Crear las filas y celdas en la hoja de Excel
    int totalRows = 10000; // Total de filas (puedes ajustarlo según tus necesidades)
    int rowsPerChunk = 100; // Filas por chunk (puedes ajustarlo según tus necesidades)
    int currentRow = 0;

    while (currentRow < totalRows) {
        int endRow = currentRow + rowsPerChunk;
        endRow = Math.min(endRow, totalRows);

        // Generar el contenido del chunk actual
        generateChunkData(sheet, currentRow, endRow);

        // Escribir el chunk en el OutputStream
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();

        // Limpiar los datos del chunk actual
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datos");

        // Actualizar el índice de la fila actual
        currentRow = endRow;
    }

    // Cerrar el libro de Excel
    workbook.close();
}

private void generateChunkData(Sheet sheet, int startRow, int endRow) {
    for (int i = startRow; i < endRow; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Valor " + (i + 1));
    }
}
```

Esta linea sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datos"); no funciona ya que intenta crear una hoja con el nombre de una hoja ya existente, y si intento obtener la referencia de esa hoja, da error de stream closed en este linea workbook.write(outputStream); la idea del funcionamiento es que toda la informacion se guarde en una misma hoja y que nada se sobreescriba.